# Defining all values of an array into array() to go to JSON file - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have been trying to solve a problem in `PHP` over the past few days, which includes sending values to a `JSON` file.

My current code retrieves data from a `mySQL` table (`ESHis`) and then redefines it into a multidimensional associative array to be sent to a `JSON` file (`jsonfun.json`) to repopulate it.

Below is my code:

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ESInfo";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$geojson = array(
   'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
   'features'  => array()
);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $ESID = $row['ESID'];
    $sqlHis = "SELECT * FROM ESHis WHERE ESID = '$ESID'";
    $resultHis = $conn->query($sqlHis);
    $index = 0;
    while($rowHis = $resultHis->fetch_assoc()){
        $plusLat = $row['lon'] + 0.0005;
        $minusLat = $row['lon'] - 0.0005;
        $plusLon = $row['lat'] + 0.0005;
        $minusLon = $row['lat'] - 0.0005;
        $dataValues = array();
        $dataValues[$index] = $rowHis['value'];
        $index++;
    }
    $feature = array(
        'type' => 'Feature',
        'geometry' => array(
        'type' => 'Polygon',
        'coordinates' => array(array(
                    array($plusLat, $plusLon),
                    array($minusLat, $plusLon),
                    array($minusLat, $minusLon),
                    array($plusLat, $minusLon),
                    array($plusLat, $plusLon)
                    )
                )),
        'properties' => array(
            'data' => array($dataValues)
        ),
    );
    array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
}
file_put_contents('jsonfun.json', json_encode($geojson, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
?>
```

The result is:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-81.369857,42.964173],
            [-81.370857,42.964173],
            [-81.370857,42.963173],
            [-81.369857,42.963173],
            [-81.369857,42.964173]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
          "data": {
          "1": 4
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem with my code is that I am only sending the final value for `properties.data()` to the JSON file. I have determined that this is because that every-time I go through the while loop, I am replacing the previous value set by the previous time through.

**My Big Question is...**

Is there any way where I can echo all the values of the array into the properties.data(), or is that not possible and should I take an alternate root?

Comment: This? `$dataValues = array();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are reseting the array `$dataValues` inside the wrong loop. But here are some considerations and a little refactoring in your code that may help you in some other things:

```
<?php
include('config.php');

/**
 * To be honest, I guess you could rethink the code to use an INNER JOIN for the
 * tables with a GROUP BY, but I'm not changing it to make it easier to show 
 * the changes
**/

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ESInfo";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$geojson = array(
   'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
   'features'  => array()
);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $ESID = $row['ESID'];

    /**
    * The following values were not being changed inside the other loop, so it
    * seems you don't need to add them there
    **/
    $plusLat = $row['lon'] + 0.0005;
    $minusLat = $row['lon'] - 0.0005;
    $plusLon = $row['lat'] + 0.0005;
    $minusLon = $row['lat'] - 0.0005;

    /** 
     * If you are really considering to use only the column 'value', then you
     * should change the * for `value`, because it makes the code execute fast
     * (less data exchanged between the server [Apache?] and MySQL). Same for the
     * other * in the beginning of the code
     **/

    /**
     * Concatenating with sprintf is safer for SQL instructions, but if the var
     * $ESID is a string you have to change %d for '%s'. For even better security,
     * consider using prepared statements
     * http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
     **/
    $sqlHis = sprintf('SELECT * FROM ESHis WHERE ESID = %d', $ESID);
    $resultHis = $conn->query($sqlHis);

    /**
     * You were reseting this variable inside the wrong loop, that's your 
     * major issue <<<<
     **/
    $dataValues = array();

    while($rowHis = $resultHis->fetch_assoc()){
        //You don't need the index
        $dataValues[] = $rowHis['value'];
    }
    /**
    * I guess you could change the previous code to
    * something like this:
    * 
    * $sqlHis = "SELECT value FROM ESHis WHERE ESID = '$ESID'";
    * $resultHis = $conn->query($sqlHis);
    * $dataValues = $resultHis->fetch_all();
    * 
    * Give it a try!
    **/

    //You don't have to use array_push here
    $geojson['features'][] = array(
        'type' => 'Feature',
        'geometry' => array(
            'type' => 'Polygon',
            'coordinates' => array(array( //Do you need the double array here?
                array($plusLat, $plusLon),
                array($minusLat, $plusLon),
                array($minusLat, $minusLon),
                array($plusLat, $minusLon),
                array($plusLat, $plusLon)
                )
            )),
        'properties' => array(
            //Do you really need to add the array inside another array here?
            //Check if it is necessary, because it seems redundant to me
            'data' => array($dataValues)
        ),
    );
}
file_put_contents('jsonfun.json', json_encode($geojson, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
?>
```